# I can't display sqlite data on AVD emulator

Tags: sqlite

] can't display sqlite data on emulator. my app launch well but doesn't show my data. It was working beforث on API 25 but not anymore. Can anyone rescue me please? Here's the blank App screen below and the red lines from the logcat:

```
04-21 04:33:24.698 12897-3026/? E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 35 in [INSERT INTO context(context_name,end_time,context_family,module_id,version,sync_state_mod_time_millis,start_time,sync_state,context_id,time_type,proto_blob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]: UNI
04-21 04:33:24.708 12897-3026/? E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 35 in [INSERT INTO context(context_name,end_time,context_family,module_id,version,sync_state_mod_time_millis,start_time,sync_state,context_id,time_type,proto_blob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]: UNI
04-21 04:33:24.708 12897-3026/? E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 35 in [INSERT INTO context(context_name,end_time,context_family,module_id,version,sync_state_mod_time_millis,start_time,sync_state,context_id,time_type,proto_blob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]: UNI
04-21 04:33:24.728 12897-3026/? E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 35 in [INSERT INTO context(context_name,end_time,context_family,module_id,version,sync_state_mod_time_millis,start_time,sync_state,context_id,time_type,proto_blob) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]:
```

Emulator showing any data

[image]

LogCat when emulator is closed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i found out that i changed the database's structure but not the functions related on it. sorry, i was working quite late last night.